# How to create multiple threads based on user input?

Tags: c, pthreads

I need to create threads based on command line argument. Do I need to create an array of pointers to declare and initialise the threads?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  int sleepTime=atoi(argv[1]);
  int noOfPoducers=atoi(argv[2]);
  int noOfConsumers=atoi(argv[3]);

  for(int i=0;i<=noOfProducers;i++){
 
    //create threads here
    pthread_t prodId1[1];     

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, like this: `pthread_t* threads = malloc(N * sizeof(pthread_t));`

Comment: @kiner_shah Thanks but is it possible to use pthread_create() in any way? I need a unique id for every thread I create that's why

Answer (score 1):

```
pthread_t *prodId1 = malloc (sizeof(pthread_t) * userInputSize);
```

That makes `prodId1` be of type `pthread_t*`, and initializes it to be a dynamically allocated block of memory of the desired size for your array.

### Edit

You can then create threads using `pthread_create` like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInputSize; i++)
{
    pthread_create(&prodId1[i], NULL, your_func, your_func_args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is it possible to use pthread_create() in any way? I need a unique id for every thread I create that's why

Comment: @shardy, please see edited answer.